# How to remove UTF-8 escape characters generated by String::from_utf8([u8])?

Tags: string, rust, utf-8, ascii

I have spent the last few hours trying to understand why String::from_utf8 includes escape characters e.g. `"u/{x}"` when converting from an array of bytes. This is from the Minesweeper exercise on Exercism which encourages the use of bytes over chars for efficiency https://exercism.org/tracks/rust/exercises/minesweeper

I apologize if I use any bad practices, I'm new to Rust

```
pub fn annotate(minefield: &[&str]) -> Vec<String> {
    const BOMB_COUNT_INDEXES: [(isize, isize); 8] = [
        (-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), 
        (0,  -1), /* · */  (0,  1), 
        (1,  -1), (1,  0), (1,  1)
    ];
    minefield.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(row_n, row_str)| {
            String::from_utf8(
                row_str.as_bytes()
                    .iter()
                    .enumerate()
                    .map(|(column_n, column_byte)| {
                        if *column_byte != b'*' {
                            let mut bombs_n: u8 = 0;
                            for (x, y) in BOMB_COUNT_INDEXES {
                                if let Some(&row) = minefield.get((row_n as isize + x) as usize) {
                                    if let Some(&c) = row.as_bytes().get((column_n as isize + y) as usize) {
                                        if c == b'*' { bombs_n += 1; }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if bombs_n > 0 { return bombs_n }
                        }
                    return *column_byte
                }).collect::<Vec<u8>>()
            ).unwrap()
        }).collect()
}
```

Comment: `String::from_utf8` does not include escape sequences, debug printing does. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ebce225639adc41dd625d65fb7098cca). Does this answer your question? [How to set input as raw string in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889091/how-to-set-input-as-raw-string-in-rust)

Comment: Where are you seeing the "escape characters" you are referring to? They're not listed in the code. If they are in some output, you need to include that in your question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are summing up the surrounding bombs into `bombs_n`. However, if you have `3` bombs, that is not the same as displaying the *character* `'3'`; `'3'` is represented in ASCII as `51`.

You need to do something like:

```
if bombs_n > 0 { return bombs_n + b'0' }
```

Or you can use [`char::from_digit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.from_digit) if you're feeling fancy.

Comment: Not sure why downvoted, I think this is exactly the problem. Although I would suggest that the fix is not to use different chars, but to use Vec<u8> instead for your data and only convert it to a string when printing it. String as the main data type for computation is just weird.